# ExpressJS: Append header to incoming request object

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to append additional header to an incoming request, it can't seem to work.

```
server.get('/', function md1(req, res, next) {
    req.setHeader('px-test-header', 1234); // Error - "req.setHeader is not a function"
    req.headers['px-test-header'] = 1234; // nothing happens
 }, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.get('px-test-header')); // always undefined
}, handler);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible?

Note - I do not want to modify the request object with additional parameter instead.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can set header before routing.
Check this code

```
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
   // set the header you wish to append
   req.headers('px-test-header', 1234);
   next();
});


router.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.headers)
});
```

Comment: This answer is either incorrect or outdated. req.headers() is not a function.

Answer (score 7):

`setHeader` is a function for response type of objects not requests as from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)

But if you still want to set the headers in request then you could do something like

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    req.headers.abc ='xyz'; 
    console.log(req);
});
```

req are stored in req.headers so you could add your custom headers here for application middle wares to use later.

Comment: Thank you! I very much needed this. I knew there was a simple answer.

Comment: Please note that the header name must be lower-cased

Comment: @RomanKishchenko your comment saved my day, thanks!

Comment: Request also has a `setHeader`, as per documentation https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_setheader_name_value

Comment: Just be careful, I just noticed that the headers that are already included with the received requests can be read via `req.get("abc)` and will return `undefined` for headers that are added via `req.headers.abc = 'xyz'`. On the other hand, `const x = req.headers.abc` will return the value of headers created via `req.headers.abc = 'xyz'` while `undefined` for headers included in the actual request received.